# "pkg install mosquitto" on Android gives error since trying to clone packages from bintray (down for maintenance)

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto, bintray

I am trying to install the Mosquitto on android device:
I have installed [termux](https://termux.com/), also trying to install Mosquitto through termux (following this [instruction](https://iotbyhvm.ooo/mqtt-broker-on-android-how-to-run-mqtt-broker-in-android/#:%7E:text=%20MQTT%20Broker%20on%20Android%20%7C%20Install%20Mosquitto,as%20MQTT%20broker%20address.%20I%20hope...%20More%20)).

However, the installation tries to access the [bintray](https://bintray.com/) website to clone required packages. Bintray is currently under maintenance for migration till 4th of July.
Wonder to ask if there is any work around or any mirror repository I can use? or is there any instruction to follow and install the Mosquitto broker executable file for Android platform?

Error message I observe is as below:

```
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:2 https://main.termux-mirror.ml stable InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to install Termux from Droid not google play store, as recommended in this [wiki page](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page)